# How to replace whitespaces in a filename?

Tags: command-line

i tried it the following way:

```
rename 'bla bla .txt' blabla.txt
```

But this doesn't work, what's the correct syntax for this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `rename` to rename just one file, use [`mv`(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) instead.

Further, to escape whitepsace, prefix it with a `\`:

`"Ubuntu One"` → `Ubuntu\ One`

Your command would be

```
mv bla\ bla.txt blabla.txt
```

- the backslash tells bash that the next character is somehow special, e.g. `\a` for 'bell', `\` for a literal space and so on

  see [`man ascii`(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ascii) for more

Alternatively, since you are now using the correct command `mv`, you can quote the filename if there are many spaces:

```
mv "bla    bla.txt" blabla.txt
```

(This would be `bla\ \ \ \ bla.txt` in escaped form)

- In bash, quoted strings (single or double quotes) are treated as a single argument, whereas unquoted strings will be split into multiple arguments, like this:

  - `["mv", "bla", "bla.txt", "blabla.txt", ]`

  and `mv` expects:

  - `["mv", "source", "destination", ]`
- Note: typing 'mv' and the first few characters of the filename and pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will give you the escaped version of the file name, making renaming quick and easy.

---

`rename` is used to batch-process the renaming of files using regular expression, as demonstrated in the example from [its man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename):

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

To strip any occurence of .bak (at the end of the string [$]) from all of the files matching "*.bak".

Comment: thanks, how would look the command if there are many whitespace in the origin filename? is there a simple regex so that there's no need to escape every single whitespace?

Comment: Updated the answer to address many spaces and single v. double quotes.

Comment: There is a difference between single and double quotes, but it's of no concern for this problem. See [this article](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3898896/Single-vs-Double-Quotes-in-Bash.htm) for the exact details of it

Answer (score 4):

[rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/prename.1.html) is specialized command for bulk renaming. Unintuitively, what we normally call "renaming" is actually a "move" to a new name:

```
mv 'bla bla .txt' blabla.txt
```

Comment: what is the difference between writing the filename in single quotes and double quotes?

Comment: Double quoting allows variables to be expanded and for process substitution; single quoting doesn't. `A=bla ; mv "$A $A .txt" blabla.txt` will move bla bla .txt, but `A=bla ; mv '$A $A .txt' blabla.txt` will look for a file actually named "$A $A .txt". Either one will work for your example though.

Answer (score 1):

```
rename "s/\s//g" "bla bla.txt"
```

s is the sed Substitute command.

\s is for whiteSpace

You are replacing with nothing.  Else replacement string goes after second forward slash.

g is for Global, i.e. replace every instance. Omitting g replaces only the first instance.

---

This command will replace whitespace with underscore in all the files:

```
rename "s/\s/_/g" *
```